# Hook into scheduler to delete node from nodequeue on unpublish

Tags: nodes, 6

I'm working on Drupal 6 site and trying to solve the following issue. If scheduler unpublished a node, it should be deleted from all nodequeues it's in.

Currently, I'm looking for hooking into the publish/unpublish events of scheduler, but I'm not finding a good example.